# how to get multiple file names in database columns at a time ? i write a code which is uploading multiple files

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using servlets in which servlet is uploading multiple files in folder at a time but it did not get all file names in database columns could any one help me in code how to get all file names in columns at a time which are uploaded by servlet

There is only one file name i get in database column like 20190416070203.192dellxps15.jpg but i want multiple file names in columns which are users uploaded like 
20190416070203.192dellxps15.jpg
20190416070203.199HuaweiMAtebookXpro.jpg
20190416070203.207s10plus.jpg

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    if (page == null) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("admin/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
        ;
    } else {
        doPost(request, response);
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String page = request.getParameter("page");



    if (page.equals("add_product")) {

        String appPath = "C:/Users/zaid/eclipse-workspace/Ecommerce-shopping/WebContent/";
        String savePath = appPath + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;

        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
        if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {
            fileSaveDir.mkdir();
        }
        Part part1 = request.getPart("file");
        String fileName1 = extractFileName(part1);

        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");
         final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
         String daformat=df.format(c.getTime());
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName =extractFileName(part);

            // refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path

            if (fileName != null && !"".equals(fileName)) {

                fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
                part.write(savePath + File.separator +""+daformat+""+fileName);
            }
        }
        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String price = request.getParameter("price");
        String category = request.getParameter("category");
        String featured = request.getParameter("featured");
        String image = request.getParameter("image");

        Product p = new Product();
        p.setName(name);
        p.setPrice(price);
        p.setCategory(category);
        p.setFeatured(featured);
        p.setImage("img/"+image);

        DB account = new DB();
        try {
            account.addProduct(p);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Product added Successfully", "Info", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("admin/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}

private String extractFileName(Part part) {
    String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
    String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
    for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length() - 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

//////////////// jsp ////////////////////////

```
<div class="signup-header">
    <h2>Add Product</h2>
 </div>

 <form method="post" action="admin" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

 <input type="hidden" name="page" value="add_product" >

 <font color="#F24638"><c:out value="${message }"></c:out></font>

    <div class="signup-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="product name goes here"  required>
    </div>
    <div class="signup-group">
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="product price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="signup-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <input type="text" name="category" placeholder="product category" required>
    </div>

    <div class="signup-group">
        <label>Featured</label>
        <input type="text" name="featured" placeholder="yes/no" required>
    </div>
    <div class="signup-group">
         <label for="fileupload"> Select an image to upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" required multiple><br>
    </div>
    <div class="signup-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Product">    
    </div>
 </form>




 <footer style="position: relative;top:60px; left: 0;bottom: 0;width: 100%; height:30%">
    <div class="footer"> &copy; 2018 Copyright:
      Zoats.com
    </div>
</footer>
```

how to get multiple images names in columns at a time in database columns with same user id like using single request in servlet.
user111 : 20190416070203.192dellxps15.jpg
user111 : 20190416070203.199HuaweiMAtebookXpro.jpg
user111 : 20190416070203.207s10plus.jpg

Comment: Did you consider creating a file table with a foreign key pointing to the user id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one `String list` and add file names in that list. and convert that String list to `comma separated String` while storing it in DB

```
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
 for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName =extractFileName(part);

            // refines the fileName in case it is an absolute path

            if (fileName != null && !"".equals(fileName)) {

                fileName = new File(fileName).getName();
                part.write(savePath + File.separator +""+daformat+""+fileName);
                fileNAmes.add(fileName);
            }
        }
        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String price = request.getParameter("price");
        String category = request.getParameter("category");
        String featured = request.getParameter("featured");
        String image = request.getParameter("image");

        Product p = new Product();
        p.setName(name);
        p.setPrice(price);
        p.setCategory(category);
        p.setFeatured(featured);
        p.setImage(StringUtils.join(fileNames , ','));
```

import StringUtils from Apache Commons

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
```

Comment: Thanks it is working . if you help me how to retrieve all these images from database

Comment: could you show me your code ??
It will be easier for me to give you a suggestion if I can see your code.

Comment: @Zaid ok so what is a problem at here ?

Comment: problem is if my database column has multiple file names . my jsp file cannot retrieve images remember i retrieve my images with image names

Comment: ok, do you want to show actual images based on the image name?

Comment: yes i want to show images which are multiple in one database column like img/20190418125114.839dellxps15.jpg,20190418125114.839HuaweiMAtebookXpro.jpg,20190418125114.839s10plus.jpg  actually if multiple image names in one column how to call all images  in jsp file

Comment: you will get image name as a String. you have to convert that String to String List. for that, you can split string by comma ",". and after that, you can get image by image name

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `account.addProduct(p);` into the `for` loop, that iterates through all the attachments.

Answer (score -1):

Dhrumil Patel here is my jsp file in which i retrieve images using jstl `

```
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 50px;"><c:out value="${row.id }"></c:out></td>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><c:out value="${row.name }"></c:out></td>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><c:out value="${row.price }"></c:out></td>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><c:out value="${row.category}"/></td>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><img src="${row.image}" height="100" width="150" ></td>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><a href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/admin?page=edit&id=${row.id}" style="color: #6bb1f8;">edit</a> ||
                <a href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/admin?page=delete&id=${row.id}" style="color:#6bb1f8;">delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </c:forEach>`
```

and here is db class code

```
public Product fetchProduct(String id) throws SQLException {
    dbConnect();
    String sql = "select * from product where id=?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, id);
    ResultSet rst = pstmt.executeQuery();
    Product p = new Product();
    while(rst.next()){

        p.setId(rst.getInt("id"));
        p.setName(rst.getString("name"));
        p.setPrice(rst.getString("price"));
        p.setCategory(rst.getString("category"));
        p.setFeatured(rst.getString("featured"));
        p.setImage(rst.getString("image"));
    }
    dbClose();
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Hi Zaid, please edit your question to provide supplements. The answer section is intended for answers only.